# Extract String from javax Response

Tags: java, rest, javax.ws.rs

Please, I have this `Response` and I want to extract the content as a `String`

```
Response res = Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(new GenericEntity<MongoType>(app) {
                }).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).build();
```

How can I do that ?

I'm using `javax.ws.rs.core` library

I'm trying `res.getEntity(String.class);` but it does not take a `String.class` on their parameter.

Comment: Which library are you using for this Response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code (`readEntity` instead of `getEntity`)

```
String resAsString= res.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: I try it also. I have this error `The method readEntity(Class<String>) is undefined for the type Response`

Comment: That's because either 1. You are using a version of your jaxrs library older than 2.0 or; 2. you have problems in your dependecie (have you defined the build path correctly?what about your libraries?)

Comment: Yes older than 2.0. why it's not possible to do this in 1.x ?

Comment: @Mehdi Because the method `readEntity` was added in version 2.0